# Embedded Redis server fails to start

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, redis

I have a Springboot project and as part of my tests I use embedded Redis server. When I run a specific test class with Intellij it works fine and tests pass. But when I use `mvn clean test` command to run tests I receive the following error:

> BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
> 'core.config.TestRedisConfiguration': Invocation of init method
> failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't start
> redis server. Check logs for details.

This is the dependency in my pom.xml file:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.kstyrc</groupId>
    <artifactId>embedded-redis</artifactId>
    <version>0.6</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

And this is my TestRedisConfiguration class:

```kotlin
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.TestConfiguration
import redis.embedded.RedisServer
import redis.embedded.RedisServerBuilder
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy

@TestConfiguration
class TestRedisConfiguration(@Value("\${redis.port:63799}") private val port: Int) {

    private val redisServer: RedisServer

    init {
        redisServer = RedisServerBuilder().port(port).build()
    }

    @PostConstruct
    fun postConstruct() {
        redisServer.start()
    }

    @PreDestroy
    fun preDestroy() {
        redisServer.stop()
    }
}
```

Comment: Is \ in `@Value("\${redis.port:63799}"` a typo?

Comment: @Smile which part you mean? I deliberately used 63799 port instead of default 6379

Comment: the \ is a necessary escaping when you use kotlin

Comment: Ah ok, my bad!.

Comment: the \ is used to escape the `$` there, by default $ sign evaluates the expression inside the `{}` and puts the result in the string.

Comment: Is there some details on the `Check logs for details`?

Comment: Check logs for details -> if you run with `-X` or `-e` or watch the detailed log, what does it say?

Comment: @Daria There is nothing in log. But I attached an external debugger and noticed in awaitRedisServerReady method of AbstranctRedisInstance class this.redisProcess.getInputStream().readLine() returns null

Comment: @zlaval adding those flags adds nothing to the log, unfortunately.

Comment: as i look at the documentation, it may try to read the config file, when you use the builder. what about `RedisServer redisServer = new RedisServer(port);` ? In the documentation there he did not use config when create with new but use when create with builder, maybe there is not a default when builder is in use. Or provide the config?
https://github.com/kstyrc/embedded-redis

Comment: @zlaval in earlier versions the constructor was protected so I used builder instead of that. I try this one.

Comment: just a tip, it is wierd it runs when you run from ide but not when build.

Comment: @zlaval just tested, it is the same with the constructor.
Indeed weird. I checked it with redis-cli and it works when I right click and run a test.

Comment: i'll try to reporoduce aftenoon, it is interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue and from what I gathered, if you are using maven's surefire plugin, then the tests are running in parallel for speed and efficiency, and the server is trying to start up multiple instances on the same port.

In my case, I was testing different properties being loaded form different profiles on my spring boot application, so I only needed to change the port in each of those profile's respective properties files. If you have a similar case, then this could work for you.

If this is not your case, you could look into a couple of ideas.

1. You can set the port to be a random number within a bounded range to start the redis server so that your server start ups don't have ports colliding. In my opinion, this option won't scale if you are running a large number of tests and there is no guarantee that even with random numbers on a bounded range that you won't run into a collision, albeit there is a reduced probability of this happening.
2. Depending on your unit testing technology (JUnit, TestNG), you can try to start your redis server as a part of a suite and then wire it to start/stop.

Comment: Adding on to this, what worked well for me was simply `@SpringBootTest(properties = {"spring.redis.port=XXXX"})` on each IT, and then feeding that config into my RedisTestConfiguration class, so that each IT class is forced to a distinct port. (To @JCB 's point I didn't use a random port to avoid any race conditions.)